# Is there any way to set the default value of all columns in a mysql database at a time?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to set all the columns(int)  default value at a time, in single query?

Comment: Do you mean in an existing row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
    ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype DEFAULT value
```

An example with int

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
    ALTER COLUMN column_name int DEFAULT 0;
```

If you actually wanted to change all the values in the table to a value instead, use:

```
UPDATE table_name
    SET column_name = value;
```

And if you wanted to change let's say all entries having old_value to new_value for column_name:

```
UPDATE table_name
    SET column_name = new_value 
    WHERE column_name = old_value;
```

Please formulate your question more clearly.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the answer to what the OP wants to ask.

Comment: @markus-tharkun Well, that is what he asked. I don't know what he wants to ask, anyway I included an update to all values in case that's what he wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Actually i am using this query to alter a column "alter table admin_seating modify mts int default 0;". Now i have 100 tables, each table have many columns, it is difficult to write an alter query fo individual columns. I want to know if that task could be completed in a single query?

Comment: I think you may be able to squash multiple columns per table by repeating the `alter column ....` part, but you'll still have to run a query for each table